# Better than binary search

Tags: java, c++, search

I basically need to have a very fast search for huge numbers (in the 2^128 range). Is there anything out there that gves better performance than binary search, ie. better than O(log n) ?

[edit] The data is sorted and pretty much evenly distributed.

Comment: Choose one language first .

Comment: Is your data sorted or not ?

Comment: Are your numbers just huge or is there a huge number of them (do you have 2^128 numbers)?

Comment: A hash table will give O(1)....

Answer (score 3):

Binary Search works only when the data is sorted. A marginal improvement over binary search is interpolation search. However, the efficiency of Interpolation Search over Binary Search depends on the distribution of your data. If the data set is pretty uniformly distributed, then interpolation search can be favored. 
This link may help, 
http://blog.imaginea.com/interpolation-search-a-search-algorithm-better-than-binary-search/